# Trim text to 340 chars

Tags: php, ellipsis

I'm pulling blog posts from a DB. I want to trim the text to a max length of 340 characters.

If the blog post is over 340 characters I want to trim the text to the last full word and add '...' on the end.

```
E.g.

NOT: In the begin....

BUT: In the ...
```

Comment: What would you like to do if the user enters a single word with length 341 characters (with no spaces at all in the post)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The other answers show you how you can make the text *roughly* 340 characters. If that's fine for you, then use one of the other answers.

But if you want a **very strict maximum** of 340 characters, the other answers won't work. You need to remember that adding the `'...'` can increase the length of the string and you need to take account of that.

```
$max_length = 340;

if (strlen($s) > $max_length)
{
    $offset = ($max_length - 3) - strlen($s);
    $s = substr($s, 0, strrpos($s, ' ', $offset)) . '...';
}
```

Note also that here I'm using the overload of `strrpos` that takes an offset to start searching directly from the correct location in the string, rather than first shortening the string.

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/PsTaI)

Comment: wouldn't doing `$.='...'` be easier instead of the last step ?

Comment: @silkAdmin: Thanks for your comment. I've made some improvements to my answer.

Comment: Cool, pretty old thread but i am sure it'll still be useful for plenty of people!

Comment: It should be noted that this produces nothing but "..." if there's no spaces in the text

Comment: Awesome! This helped a lot.. Thank you

Answer (score 29):

It seems like you would want to first trim the text down to 340 characters exactly, then find the location of the last ' ' in the string and trim down to that amount. Like this:

```
$string = substr($string, 0, 340);
$string = substr($string, 0, strrpos($string, ' ')) . " ...";
```

Comment: Needs some polish (check if string needs to get shortened, etc) but short and sweet.

Answer (score 18):

If you have the mbstring extension enabled (which is on most servers nowadays), you can use the mb_strimwidth function.

```
echo mb_strimwidth($string, 0, 340, '...');
```

Answer (score 7):

try:

```
preg_match('/^.{0,340}(?:.*?)\b/siu', $text, $matches);
echo $matches[0] . '...';
```

Comment: By default, the `.` does not match line breaks. So when there are line breaks before the 340th character, it will not work. Adding a `s` modifier in the end will do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

I put the answer of John Conde in a method:

```
function softTrim($text, $count, $wrapText='...'){

    if(strlen($text)>$count){
        preg_match('/^.{0,' . $count . '}(?:.*?)\b/siu', $text, $matches);
        $text = $matches[0];
    }else{
        $wrapText = '';
    }
    return $text . $wrapText;
}
```

Examples:

```
echo softTrim("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text", 10);
/* Output: Lorem Ipsum... */

echo softTrim("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text", 33);
/* Output: Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text */

echo softTrim("LoremIpsumissimplydummytext", 10);
/* Output: LoremIpsumissimplydummytext... */
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try using functions that comes with PHP , such as wordwrap

```
print wordwrap($text,340) . "...";
```

Answer (score 0):

function trim_characters( $text, $length = 340 ) {

```
$length = (int) $length;
$text = trim( strip_tags( $text ) );

if ( strlen( $text ) > $length ) {
    $text = substr( $text, 0, $length + 1 );
    $words = preg_split( "/[\s]|&nbsp;/", $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY );
    preg_match( "/[\s]|&nbsp;/", $text, $lastchar, 0, $length );
    if ( empty( $lastchar ) )
        array_pop( $words );

    $text = implode( ' ', $words ); 
}

return $text;
```

}

Use this function trim_characters() to trims a string of words to a specified number of characters, gracefully stopping at white spaces.
I think this is helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

**Why this way?**

- I like the *regex* solution over *substring*, to catch any other than whitespace word breaks (interpunction etc.)
- John Condoe's solution is not perfectly correct, since it trim text to 340 characters **and then** finish the last word (so will often be longer than desired)

Actual *regex* solution is very simple:

```
/^(.{0,339}\w\b)/su
```

Full method in PHP could look like this:

```
function trim_length($text, $maxLength, $trimIndicator = '...')
{
        if(strlen($text) > $maxLength) {

            $shownLength = $maxLength - strlen($trimIndicator);

            if ($shownLength < 1) {

                throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Second argument for ' . __METHOD__ . '() is too small.');
            }

            preg_match('/^(.{0,' . ($shownLength - 1) . '}\w\b)/su', $text, $matches);                               

            return (isset($matches[1]) ? $matches[1] : substr($text, 0, $shownLength)) . $trimIndicator ;
        }

        return $text;
}
```

More explanation:

- `$shownLength` is to keep very strict limit (like Mark Byers mentioned)
- Exception is thrown in case given length was too small
- `\w\b` part is to avoid whitespace or interpunction at the end (see 1 below)
- In case first word would be longer than desired max length, that word will be brutally cut

---

1. Despite the fact that in question result `In the ...` is described as desired, I feel `In the...` is more smooth (also don't like `In the,...` etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution

```
$text_to_be_trim= "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry standard.";
if(strlen($text_to_be_trim) > 20)   
    $text_to_be_trim= substr($text_to_be_trim,0,20).'....';
```

For multi-byte text

```
$stringText= "UTIL CONTROL DISTRIBUCION AMARRE CIGÜEÑAL";
$string_encoding = 'utf8';
$s_trunc =  mb_substr($stringText, 0, 37, $string_encoding);
echo $s_trunc;
```

Comment: This one may fail when you meet an special char. Just happened to me with ü. If you chop right there, it fails. If you go one character further, it works. So, Mark Byers answer is my preferred. Works perfectly.

Comment: Could you please share the text which is to be trimmed? So that i can check my solution..

Comment: Sure. Try this and cut in in the Ü: "UTIL CONTROL DISTRIBUCION AMARRE CIGÜEÑAL". Letter 40 for me.

Comment: Thanks for the string & If you want trim multi-byte text please use [mb_substr](http://php.net/mb_substr) and i'm updating my answer for special character also