# jQuery text truncation (read more style)

Tags: jquery, text, trim

My question is very similar to "[Trim text to 340 chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104653/trim-text-to-340-chars)" but in **jQuery**. It sounded very straight forward but when I searched around I couldn't find any reference for it.

Ok, I have a div `$('#content')` I want to trim the text to 'x' amount of characters lets say '600' **BUT** I don't want it to break the word it self! Like NOT '***The Ques...***' BUT '***The Questions...***'.

**What happens to the rest of the text?** Well, I hide it and will show it on request! But wait, it should first remove the '***...***' and show the text right after where it hid.

Here is the sample structure for $('#content'):

```
<div id="content">
    <p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary,Over many a quaint and curious volume of forgotten lore.</p>
    <p>Writing example text is very boring.</p>
    <p>Specially when you are dumb enough not to copy and paste. Oh!</p>
    <p>Once it sheltered the rogues and rapscallions of the British Empire; now Kangaroo Island is ready and waiting for some derring-do of your own. Venture into the rugged wilds of the island, traversing untamed bushland and pristine beaches seeking out seal, penguin and sea lion colonies. Meet the land loving locals - koalas, goannas, echidnas and the island's own species of kangaroo. </p>
</div>
```

**How it should load:**

> Once upon a midnight dreary, while I
>   pondered weak and weary,Over many a
>   quaint and curious volume of forgotten
>   lore.
>
> Writing example text is... [Read
>   More]

**After click on 'Read More':**

> Once upon a midnight dreary, while I
>   pondered weak and weary,Over many a
>   quaint and curious volume of forgotten
>   lore.
>
> Writing example text is very boring.
>
> Specially when you are dumb enough not
>   to copy and paste. Oh!
>
> Once it sheltered the rogues and
>   rapscallions of the British Empire;
>   now Kangaroo Island is ready and
>   waiting for some derring-do of your
>   own. Venture into the rugged wilds of
>   the island, traversing untamed
>   bushland and pristine beaches seeking
>   out seal, penguin and sea lion
>   colonies. Meet the land loving locals
>   - koalas, goannas, echidnas and the island's own species of kangaroo.

---

**UPDATE:**
I have found these two plug-ins that do basically same job as this best answer. However the best answer has some functionalities that those plug-ins don't have and vice versa!

- [jTruncate](http://blog.jeremymartin.name/2008/02/jtruncate-text-truncation-for-jquery.html)
- [Truncate](http://www.reindel.com/truncate/)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This code presumes that tags will always be balanced, and that the only tag without a closer will be `<br />` (though this could be easily remedied if needed).

```
#content {
    width: 800px;
    clear:both;
    clip:auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.revealText {
    background: white; /* Strange problem in ie8 where the sliding animation goes too far
                            if revealText doesn't have a background color!  */
}
.hiddenText {

}
.readMore {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: blue;
}
.ellipsis {
    color: black;
}

$('document').ready(function() {

truncate('#content');

$('.readMore').on('click', function() {
    var $hidden = $('.hiddenText');
    if($hidden.is(':hidden')) {
        $hidden.show();
        $(this).insertAfter($('#content')).children('.readMoreText').text(' [Read Less] ').siblings().hide();
    } else {
        $(this).appendTo($('.revealText')).children('.readMoreText').text(' [Read More] ').siblings().show();
        $hidden.hide();
    }
});

$('.readMore').click();

function truncate(element) {
    $(element + ' p').css({display: 'inline'});

    var theText = $(element).html();        // Original Text
    var item;                               // Current tag or text area being iterated
    var convertedText = '<span class="revealText">';    // String that will represent the finished result
    var limit = 154;                        // Max characters (though last word is retained in full)
    var counter = 0;                        // Track how far we've come (compared to limit)
    var lastTag;                            // Hold a reference to the last opening tag
    var lastOpenTags = [];                  // Stores an array of all opening tags (they get removed as tags are closed)
    var nowHiding = false;                  // Flag to set to show that we're now in the hiding phase

    theText = theText.replace(/[\s\n\r]{2,}/g, ' ');            // Consolidate multiple white-space characters down to one. (Otherwise the counter will count each of them.)
    theText = theText.replace(/(<[^<>]+>)/g,'|*|SPLITTER|*|$1|*|SPLITTER|*|');                      // Find all tags, and add a splitter to either side of them.
    theText = theText.replace(/(\|\*\|SPLITTER\|\*\|)(\s*)\|\*\|SPLITTER\|\*\|/g,'$1$2');           // Find consecutive splitters, and replace with one only.
    theText = theText.replace(/^[\s\t\r]*\|\*\|SPLITTER\|\*\||\|\*\|SPLITTER\|\*\|[\s\t\r]*$/g,''); // Get rid of unnecessary splitter (if any) at beginning and end.
    theText = theText.split(/\|\*\|SPLITTER\|\*\|/);            // Split theText where there's a splitter. Now we have an array of tags and words.

    for(var i in theText) {                                     // Iterate over the array of tags and words.
        item = theText[i];                                      // Store current iteration in a variable (for convenience)
        lastTag = lastOpenTags[lastOpenTags.length - 1];        // Store last opening tag in a variable (for convenience)
        if( !item.match(/<[^<>]+>/) ) {                         // If 'item' is not a tag, we have text
            if(lastTag && item.charAt(0) == ' ' && !lastTag[1].match(/span|SPAN/)) item = item.substr(1);   // Remove space from beginning of block elements (like IE does) to make results match cross browser
            if(!nowHiding) {                                        // If we haven't started hiding yet...
                counter += item.length;                             // Add length of text to counter.
                if(counter >= limit) {                              // If we're past the limit...
                    var length = item.length - 1;                   // Store the current item's length (minus one).
                    var position = (length) - (counter - limit);    // Get the position in the text where the limit landed.
                    while(position != length) {                     // As long as we haven't reached the end of the text...
                        if( !!item.charAt(position).match(/[\s\t\n]/) || position == length )   // Check if we have a space, or are at the end.
                            break;                                  // If so, break out of loop.
                        else position++;                            // Otherwise, increment position.
                    }
                    if(position != length) position--;
                    var closeTag = '', openTag = '';                // Initialize open and close tag for last tag.
                    if(lastTag) {                                   // If there was a last tag,
                        closeTag = '</' + lastTag[1] + '>';         // set the close tag to whatever the last tag was,
                        openTag = '<' + lastTag[1] + lastTag[2] + '>';  // and the open tag too.
                    }
                    // Create transition from revealed to hidden with the appropriate tags, and add it to our result string
                    var transition = '<span class="readMore"><span class="ellipsis">...</span><span class="readMoreText"> [Read More] </span></span>' + closeTag + '</span><span class="hiddenText">' + openTag;
                    convertedText += (position == length)   ? (item).substr(0) + transition
                                                                : (item).substr(0,position + 1) + transition + (item).substr(position + 1).replace(/^\s/, '&nbsp;');
                    nowHiding = true;       // Now we're hiding.
                    continue;               // Break out of this iteration.
                }
            }
        } else {                                                // Item wasn't text. It was a tag.
            if(!item.match(/<br>|<BR>/)) {                      // If it is a <br /> tag, ignore it.
                if(!item.match(/\//)) {                         // If it is not a closing tag...
                    lastOpenTags.push(item.match(/<(\w+)(\s*[^>]*)>/));     // Store it as the most recent open tag we've found.
                } else {                                                    // If it is a closing tag.
                    if(item.match(/<\/(\w+)>/)[1] == lastOpenTags[lastOpenTags.length - 1][1]) {    // If the closing tag is a paired match with the last opening tag...
                        lastOpenTags.pop();                                                         // ...remove the last opening tag.
                    }
                    if(item.match(/<\/[pP]>/)) {            // Check if it is a closing </p> tag
                        convertedText += ('<span class="paragraphBreak"><br> <br> </span>');    // If so, add two line breaks to form paragraph
                    }
                }
            }
        }   
        convertedText += (item);            // Add the item to the result string.
    }
    convertedText += ('</span>');           // After iterating over all tags and text, close the hiddenText tag.
    $(element).html(convertedText);         // Update the container with the result.
}
});


<div id="content">
    <p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary,Over many a quaint and curious volume of forgotten lore.</p>
    <p>Writing example text is very boring.</p>
    <p>Specially when you are dumb enough not to copy and paste. Oh!</p>
    <p>Once it sheltered the rogues and rapscallions of the British Empire; now Kangaroo Island is ready and waiting for some derring-do of your own. Venture into the rugged wilds of the island, traversing untamed bushland and pristine beaches seeking out seal, penguin and sea lion colonies. Meet the land loving locals - koalas, goannas, echidnas and the island's own species of kangaroo. </p>
</div>
```

Comment: @patrick: Thanks for your answer, It did not perform completely as I hoped for it to do. Changing the opacity will hide the text but it won't slide the page up and down. Plus the tricky bit I am trying to figure out is that if 100 character reaches inside a '<p>' tag; when you click view more it will remove the '...' and shows the rest of the content as it originally should have. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: @Mazzi - I just did the opacity to visually demonstrate the two halves. Since they are separate, it is simple to slide the hidden part up or down. I just didn't implement it. The way this works, it will never split in the middle of a tag. Only characters in the *words* are added to the counter. The counter passes right over the tags. So it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @Mazzi - Question for you. If you want the text to be hidden via a slideup, then how do you want it to work when the limit ends up in the middle of a line?

Comment: @patrick: Sorry didn't realize it was intentionaly left like that. Answer: Here is where I am puzzled. Ideally, if limit reaches in a middle of a line then rest should be replaced with '...' then when you click on 'read more' it should remove the '...' and continues the rest of the text - Just right where it cuts off. Thanks

Comment: @Mazzi - Would it be an acceptable solution if the script were to replace the `<p>` tags with `<span>` tags along with a pair of `<br />` tags to make the paragraph? We need this to be inline, but `<p>` tags are block, and you get unexpected results with block tags inside of inline tags.

Comment: @Mazzi - I've been re-working this a bit. Made some changes, eliminated some problems. Will have it posted within a day or so.

Comment: @Mazzi - Fixed some bugs, found more and fixed those, made things run more efficiently. Both the JS and CSS were updated. I'll probably tinker a bit more in the future. Will comment here when I do. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: @patrick - Well done mate, I am still trying to incorporate it into my current template. One quick question: How would you eliminate the sliding effect and make it just hide and show? I tried various ways but it doesn't like it.

P.S. You should make this a jQuery plugin.

Comment: @Mazzi - Very simple. Just changed the click event handler. Basically, after the truncate() method runs, the text is split into two classes: revealText and hiddenText. From there, you can manipulate them however you wish using jQuery (or whatever).

Comment: item `if (!item.match(/\//)) {`

should be
`if (!item.match(/<\//)) {`

otherwise it will fail on '<a href="http://">a</a>'

Answer (score 24):

The following works for limiting the amount of text if you don't mind losing the paragraph tags.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var shortText = $("#content").text()    // get the text within the div
    .trim()    // remove leading and trailing spaces
    .substring(0, 600)    // get first 600 characters
    .split(" ") // separate characters into an array of words
    .slice(0, -1)    // remove the last full or partial word
    .join(" ") + "..."; // combine into a single string and append "..."
</script>
```

Comment: @Tim: is `split().slice().join()` faster then `trim().substring(0, lastIndexOf(' '))` ?

Comment: @Mendy Good point. lastIndexOf should be faster due to less iterations over the entire string.

Answer (score 13):

Well, There is a plugin for it. [jQuery Expander](http://plugins.learningjquery.com/expander/).

Comment: This is what I was looking for and it's been maintained by Karl Swedberg on Github https://github.com/kswedberg/jquery-expander

Answer (score -1):

You can use jQuery Expander Plugin to do this easily.
  http://plugins.learningjquery.com/expander/index.html#download?