# How Can I Truncate A String In jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I have long titles and want truncate them but in a way that no words break, I mean the cutting happen between words not cutting a word.

How can I do it using jquery?

Answer (score 134, accepted):

**From:**
[jQuery text truncation (read more style)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248742/jquery-text-truncation-read-more-style/2249591#2249591)

Try this:

```
var title = "This is your title";

var shortText = jQuery.trim(title).substring(0, 10)
    .split(" ").slice(0, -1).join(" ") + "...";
```

- [Tested here](http://jsfiddle.net/AxyXr/243/)

And you can also use a plugin:

- [jQuery Expander Plugin](http://plugins.learningjquery.com/expander/)

As a extension of String

```
String.prototype.trimToLength = function(m) {
  return (this.length > m) 
    ? jQuery.trim(this).substring(0, m).split(" ").slice(0, -1).join(" ") + "..."
    : this;
};
```

Use as

```
"This is your title".trimToLength(10);
```

Comment: $.trim(title) was suggested - I agree since it will handle IE<9 too

Comment: It's an edge case, but if the first word of the title is 10 or more characters, this returns "..."

Comment: Doesn't this fail if the it cuts right at the end of the word? ie: 'Test test sentence'.trimToLength(9) will cut out the second test, even though it's perfectly valid.

Comment: Good answer. I would opt for using `&hellip;` rather than three separate dots though, but its really a matter of preference.

Comment: Here is the single character for 3 dots: `…`

Answer (score 45):

The solution above won't work if the original string has no spaces.

Try this:

```
var title = "This is your title";
var shortText = jQuery.trim(title).substring(0, 10)
                          .trim(this) + "...";
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much for providing this patch.

Comment: This adds the omission( the three dots ) when the string is shorter than 10 characters >jQuery.trim("test").substring(0, 10).trim(this) + "...";
 "test..."

Answer (score 38):

```
  function truncateString(str, length) {
     return str.length > length ? str.substring(0, length - 3) + '...' : str
  }
```

Comment: The only answer that doesn't add the dots if the string is shorter then the max length. And includes the dots in the calculation...

Comment: This solution can handle strings shorter than max length, but does truncate mid-word.

Answer (score 12):

Instead of using jQuery, use css property `text-overflow:ellipsis`. It will automatically truncate the string.

```
.truncated { display:inline-block; 
             max-width:100px; 
             overflow:hidden; 
             text-overflow:ellipsis; 
             white-space:nowrap; 
           }
```

Comment: It actually can break words but it's just what I was searching for. Also, nice mustache.

Comment: I think it will not work for multi lines text as in paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

with prototype and without space :

```
 String.prototype.trimToLength = function (trimLenght) {
    return this.length > trimLenght ? this.substring(0, trimLenght - 3) + '...' : this
};
```