# How to shorten plain HTML text

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How Can I Truncate A String In jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4637942/how-can-i-truncate-a-string-in-jquery)

I have this code which allows to display only a certain amount of characters:

```
$(function(){
  $(".description").each(function(i){
    len=$(this).text().length;
    if(len>10)
    {
      $(this).text($(this).text().substr(0,260)+'...');
    }
  });       
});
    });
```

The problem is that it doesn't distinguish between words, so it cuts in the middle of the words. What can I do to make it cut only after the last word?

Comment: have you tried ellipsis? related: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/

Comment: something with `lastindeof()`

Comment: to answer your question, instead of having a fixed number like '260', you have to pick the last index of character space (' ') or if it doesn't exist, then you can have a default number like 260 for that case.

Comment: @Youss as said by Purmou, it is a duplicate question.

Comment: I have answered a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199352/smart-way-to-shorten-long-strings-with-javascript/1199420#1199420