# jQuery table width of title

Tags: jquery, html-table, width, col

I have a `table` with short title but long cells (`td`).
Is it possible to make the columns width to the smallest possible width of title ?

Example:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>phone</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Santa</td>
        <td>20938570987098709870298349082456</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

So, the column "phone" should show "20....."

Is it possible?

Comment: duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4637942/how-can-i-truncate-a-string-in-jquery ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit tougher if you need to be exact on the width and you're not using a monospace font.

```
$("th").each(function () {
   var chars = $(this).text().length;
   $("td").eq($(this).index()).each(function () {
      if ($(this).text().length > chars) {
         $(this).text($(this).text().substring(0, chars) + '...');
      }
   });
});
```

Not tested or optimized; just a proof-of-concept.