# show limited text using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to show limited text (50 character) using the jquery . please let me how can I do it.
I'm using the following code.

```
var ta = $('title', item).text().replace(/\(.*?\)/, "");
```

The out put of this is "Failure to qualify for Africa Cup of Nations could spell sorry end for Eto’o’s international".I want to show only 50 character.

Comment: better answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4637942/how-can-i-truncate-a-string-in-jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var ta = $('title', item).text();
var edited = ta.substring(0,50);
```

***[Read More](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp)***

Above code is created assuming that *item* is the scope

Or you can write this in one line using Jquery chaining.

```
var ta = $('title', item).text().substring(0,50);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like this:

```
String sOut = $('title', item).text().substring(0,50);
```

Though I don't know what `item` is doing there. :|

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var ta = $('title', item).text().substring(0,50)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(ta.length > 50){
   ta = ta.substring(0, 47) + '...';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var ta = $('title', item).text();
ta = ta.substring(0,50);
```