# Text-overflow on Select Multiple?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to apply a text-overflow on the options of a select with multiple. However, I can't seem to touch the options text.

Here is my HTML:

```
 <select id="multiselect" multiple="" size="6">

   <option value="123456780123456780123456780123456780123456780123456780" selected="selected">123456780123456780123456780123456780123456780123456780</option>
    <option value="other" selected="selected">other</option>
</select>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
#multiselect {
width: 222px;
border-top: 2px solid #ccc;
float: none;
background: #fff;
outline: none;
margin-right: 0;
margin-left: 5px;
border-radius: 0;
margin-bottom: 11px;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

#multiselect option {
  overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space:nowrap;
 width:222px;
}
```

I know the text-overflow is repeated when it should (I think) only be applied to the option, but I wanted to demonstrate how it wasn't working in either solution.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I couldn't find a CSS-only solution, so I took some inspiration from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4637942/how-can-i-truncate-a-string-in-jquery) (not the selected answer, but the other, which is more accurate and handles non-spaced answers) and  came up with this JS Loop achieve the goal:

```
$('#multiselect option').each( function() {
        //Manually make the ellipsis, since CSS3 gets weird with select multiple.
        if (dictionary_length($(this).text()) > 30) {
            $(this).text($.trim($(this).text()).substring(0, 28).trim(this) + "...");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Move your `white-space: nowrap` up onto the select itself, not just the options.

Worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

This styling worked for me with SCSS:

```
select {
  width: 100%;
  option {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
  }
}
```