# Intermittent Truncation using Jquery.dotdotdot

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, ellipsis, jquery-dotdotdot

I am using jquery.dotdotdot to truncate lengthy text on the Tiles on the Carousel. Truncation sometimes is intermittently truncating less than the expected result. (e.g. truncate a text to 4 lines but at some point it only truncates to 3 lines.)

On my CSS the formula I used to have 4 lines is Max-height = line-height * 4.

Appreciate any response. Thanks.
JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
                EllipsisConfigFunction($(".module-body.dot-ellipsis"));

    function EllipsisConfigFunction($elements) {
        $elements.each(function () {
            var $element = $(this);
            $element.dotdotdot({
                // configuration goes here
                ellipsis: '... ',

                /*  How to cut off the text/html: 'word'/'letter'/'children' */
                wrap: 'word',

                /*  Wrap-option fallback to 'letter' for long words */
                fallbackToLetter: true,

                /*  jQuery-selector for the element to keep and put after the ellipsis. */
                after: null,

                /*  Whether to update the ellipsis: true/'window' */
                watch: true,

                /*  Optionally set a max-height, can be a number or function.
                    If null, the height will be measured. */
                height: null,

                /*  Deviation for the height-option. */
                tolerance: 0,

                /*  Callback function that is fired after the ellipsis is added,
                    receives two parameters: isTruncated(boolean), orgContent(string). */
                callback: function (isTruncated, orgContent) { },

                lastCharacter: {

                    /*  Remove these characters from the end of the truncated text. */
                    remove: [' ', ',', ';', '.', '!', '?'],

                    /*  Don't add an ellipsis if this array contains
                        the last character of the truncated text. */
                    noEllipsis: []
                }
            });
        });
    }
    });
```

CSS:

```
.module-body{
            max-height: 80px;
            overflow: hidden;
            position: relative;
            text-align: left;
            line-height:20px;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not posted any of your code my best suggestions are as follow:

```
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/
https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/
http://stackoverflow.com/a/4637957/5833940
```

See if those fixes your problem.

bests :)

Comment: Thanks @SG1Asgard. I updated the Question with the code. Thanks for the suggestion but I need a cross browser multi line ellipsis. Appreciate it.